# Trying to map inputs to the questions of radio type

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, input

Trying to get the radio type inputs but it doesn't work. BUt Iam getting this response I need legit iputs there. Tried multiple things like adding it into array and in that case, I got [data data] something like this.
[image]

```
function showRadioOptions(questionId, data, mKey, qLevel) {
  

data = data.sort((a, b) => a.orderNo - b.orderNo);
  let radioOptions: any = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    radioOptions = radioOptions.concat(
      `<input type='radio' className='showChildQuestion qid_${questionId}' name='${questionId}' id='${questionId}' value=${data[i].id} data-key='${mKey}' data-ishierarchy='${data[i].isHierarchy}' data-hierarchy-question='${data[i].hierarchyQuestionId}' data-current-question='${questionId}' data-question-level='${data[i].questionLevel}'> ${data[i].optionText} <br/>`
    );
  }
  return radioOptions;
}

function Radio(questionId, options, mKey, qLevel) {
  return "<br/>" + showRadioOptions(questionId, options, mKey, qLevel);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "radio type inputs"? The `input's` `type` is `'radio'`, so what do you need here? What do you mean with "I am getting this response I need legit niputs there." - is that some kind of error message - if so, where does it appear and what does it say exactly? Additionally, your question is tagged as `TypeScript` but the parameters for your functions aren't typed.

Comment: I want to show inputs , not the string as shown in photo

Comment: How are you adding that string of inputs to the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function showRadioOptions(questionId, data, mKey, qLevel) {
  data = data.sort((a, b) => a.orderNo - b.orderNo);
  let radioOptions: any = "";
  radioOptions = data.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          className={"showChildQuestion qid_" + questionId}
          name={questionId}
          id={questionId}
          value={item.id}
          data-key={mKey}
          data-ishierarchy={item.isHierarchy}
          data-hierarchy-question={item.hierarchyQuestionId}
          data-current-question={questionId}
          data-question-level={item.questionLevel}
        />
        {item.optionText} <br />
      </label>
    );
  });
  return radioOptions;
}

function Radio(questionId, options, mKey, qLevel) {
  return showRadioOptions(questionId, options, mKey, qLevel);
}
```