# Trying to get inputs of radio type after mapping but

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, input

Trying to get the radio type inputs but it doesn't work. BUt Iam getting this response I need legit iputs there. Tried multiple things like adding it into array and in that case, I got [data data] something like this.
[image]

```
function showRadioOptions(questionId, data, mKey, qLevel) {
  

data = data.sort((a, b) => a.orderNo - b.orderNo);
  let radioOptions: any = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    radioOptions = radioOptions.concat(
      `<input type='radio' className='showChildQuestion qid_${questionId}' name='${questionId}' id='${questionId}' value=${data[i].id} data-key='${mKey}' data-ishierarchy='${data[i].isHierarchy}' data-hierarchy-question='${data[i].hierarchyQuestionId}' data-current-question='${questionId}' data-question-level='${data[i].questionLevel}'> ${data[i].optionText} <br/>`
    );
  }
  return radioOptions;
}

function Radio(questionId, options, mKey, qLevel) {
  return "<br/>" + showRadioOptions(questionId, options, mKey, qLevel);
}
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74876526/trying-to-map-inputs-to-the-questions-of-radio-type/74886271#74886271](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74876526/trying-to-map-inputs-to-the-questions-of-radio-type/74886271#74886271)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this could be helpful for you..

```html
<script>
  function showRadioOptions(questionId, data, mKey, qLevel) {
    data = data.sort((a, b) => a.orderNo - b.orderNo);
    let radioOptions = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      radioOptions = radioOptions.concat(
        `<label for="${questionId+i}">
                    <input type='radio' className='showChildQuestion qid_${questionId}' name='${questionId}' id='${questionId+i}' value=${data[i].id} data-key='${mKey}' data-ishierarchy='${data[i].isHierarchy}' data-hierarchy-question='${data[i].hierarchyQuestionId}' data-current-question='${questionId}' data-question-level='${data[i].questionLevel}'> ${data[i].optionText} <br/></label>`
      );
    }
    return radioOptions;
  }

  function Radio(questionId, options, mKey, qLevel) {
    return "<br/>" + showRadioOptions(questionId, options, mKey, qLevel);
  }

  var question_date = [{
      id: '1',
      optionText: 'Lorem',
      isHierarchy: true,
      hierarchyQuestionId: "some text",
      questionLevel: "123"
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      optionText: 'Ipsum',
      isHierarchy: true,
      hierarchyQuestionId: "some text",
      questionLevel: "456"
    },
  ];
  document.write(Radio('question_name', question_date, '345', '123'));
</script>
```

Comment: Though it did not work but I appreciate your time and efforts.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).